# WADL location : How to find WADL location in JAX-RS application?

Tags: jax-rs

I have developed JAX-RS REST Application and also I have generated WADL. How to find the WADL location?

For example in Jax-ws the wsdl can be find using the URL like [http://192.168.1.39:8083/application/ApplicationService?wsdl]

Like that how to find location WADL in JAX-RS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Jersey, you will find it at http://your.application/resource.path/application.wadl where resource.path is the path defined in your web.xml.

Comment: Thank you so much....Its working i got WADL file location when i used url in above manner..

Comment: Cool. So, can you mark the answer as accepted? This will help future searches on this topic.

Comment: So which application above is static and which is dynamic?
Is it:   
`http://{your.app}/{resource.paht}/application.wadl` OR `http://{your.app}/{resource.paht}/{application}.wadl`

Comment: application.wadl is static don't change it and don't need resource path either. http://{your.app}/application.wadl

Answer (score -1):

if you use jaxrs you will get  wadl at 
http://your.application/resource.path/application?_wadl and it is also mentioned over here http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html